# Deployed site only shows a page to a documentation page with a movie

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a web app to Azure. In the Azure portal, my resource group, app plan, sql server, and sql database are successfully deployed.  When I browse to my site, a page tells me my service has deployed and wants me to go to a documentation page. My site will not show up. I have deleted my resource group 3 times and re-deployed w/ the same results.

[image: Browse to my site shows this]

I deployed from within VS 15 Community (web deploy).Right clicked on my project and deployed my site along w/ my database. Azure portal shows everything uploaded. When I browsed to my site, I got the image you see in my post.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok... you haven't given us any details about your deployment, aside from the fact that you deployed. With no details, it's anyone's guess what's going wrong. Please edit your question to give us more info. The only thing I was able to glean from your screencap is that you deployed as a web app (now properly tagged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Azure app service new **hostingstart.html** page. If you do not want it displays as default page of your website, please go Application Settings > Default documents and specify [Default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure#application-settings) for your website.

[image]

I include **default.aspx** file in my application, and it will be displayed as default document.

[image]